# 'fs-extra' symlink not permitted when running as administrator and with the policy added, running mklink myself works?

Tags: node.js, symlink, serverless, fs-extra, serverless-plugins

I'm trying to use [this plugin](https://github.com/Butterwire/serverless-plugin-monorepo) together with serverless to bundle my dependencies using symlinks. Under the hood it uses fs.symlink from `fs-extra` as follows:

```
async function link (target, f) {
  await fs.ensureDir(path.dirname(f))
  await fs.symlink(target, f)
    .catch(e => {
      if (e.code === 'EEXIST') {
        return
      }
      throw e
    })
}
```

But I get `operation not permitted symlink ->` even when:

- Running as administrator
- Local Policy updated, with the user added the ability to perform symlinks
- mklink works from the commandline without an issue, in the same folder and all.

No idea what to do anymore around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need use Windows in [Developer mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/292914/what-is-developer-mode-in-windows-10/).

Otherwise you'll need to specify the 'junction' type in the source code while on Windows.

```
async function link (target, f) {
  await fs.ensureDir(path.dirname(f))
  await fs.symlink(target, f, 'junction')
    .catch(e => {
      if (e.code === 'EEXIST') {
        return
      }
      throw e
    })
}
```

Comment: I am using windows in developer mode, the issue requiring to use the junction type has been resolved with nodejs 10 and I'm running on 10.16.3 :(

Comment: I tested specifically for serverless and the second solution solved the problem for me (adding 'junction'). Before the change: `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'fs-extra' -> 'C:\...\node_modules\fs-extra'` and then after `Serverless: Starting Offline: dev/us-east-1.` On Node v10.15.0. But the Developer mode solution seems to work outside of this specific package so it needs further investigating.

Comment: I can't modify the actual package as it's a dependency, but I discussed the issue on github with the package owner and he made this change, using junction, which now works, thanks